# What is the difference between Mega Charizard X and Mega Charizard Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I am playing Pokemon X and have two Charizard. One has the Pokemon X mega stone and one has the Pokemon Y mega stone (I got it by trading).

Both mega evolutions are great, but one thing bothers me: is there a difference between the mega evolutions? Besides the color, is there anything different about the Charizard mega evolutions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mega Charizard X loses its Flying Type and gains Dragon Typing, affecting the Same Type Attack Bonus (STAB) of Flying & Dragon moves respectively. It also gets Tough Claws, an ability that increases the strength of physical moves. Its primary boosted stat is Attack

Mega Charizard Y gains the Drought Ability (upping the power of it's fire attacks, and weakening water). Its primary boosted stat is Special Attack. This version of Charizard remains Fire/Flying.

If you have one of each, they should look pretty different in terms of EVs and Movesets. Charizard X would focus more on Physical moves, and drop Flying moves in favour of Dragon ones. Charizard Y would focus on strong Special Attack Fire moves, with Flying for extra coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Against **Stealth Rock**, Mega Charizard X would be better. They would inflict 50% damage at Mega Charizard Y due to his double weakness to rock type (Fly/Fire), where Mega Charizard X would lost *only* 25% (only 1 weakness, Fire). You can find more informations about **Stealth Rock** on this [Bulbapedia page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stealth_Rock_(move)).

As said by [Robotnik](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/149425/240440), these 2 mega evolutions don't have the same double type, and their coverage would be totally different :

- Mega Charizard Y could use **Solar Beam** thanks to his ability *Drought* which is equivalent of **Sunny Day** (without a turn used), and always have his immunity to Ground type moves, or any spikes; but **Stealth Rock** deals a lot of damage, so without any recover, you can't remove your Mega Charizard Y of the battle ground besides seeing him die at the 2nd time he would return on battle
- Mega Charizard X is more physical thanks to his ability *Tough Claws* (+30% power of physical attacks), he lost his double weakness to Rock moves (and **Stealth Rock**) due to Dragon type. But after Mega evolution, he would be affected by Ground type moves, and any others spikes, so you must chose correctly when you want to mega evolved him, or you could see him OHKO with a well placed **Earthquake** (for experience, I was able to do it with a Krokorible Choice Scarf blocked onto *Earthquake* move).

If you want to build a strategic team on one of this Mega Charizard, think about team which would take advantage of *Drought* ability of Y form, or huge physical attacks for X form (but don't use this one as Ground counter type).